# How to check if free page reporting is supported by qemu?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, qemu, kvm, virtio

I know that we can login into the QMP shell and run "device_add driver=virtio-balloon-pci,help" and see if there is "free-page-reporting" option or not but Is there any other way to where we can check?

```
]$ sudo /venv/bin/qmp-shell -H /kvm/instances/Idak7va511eky8rkx/write-qemu/monitor-debug.sock
Welcome to the HMP shell!
Connected to QEMU 4.2.1

(QEMU) device_add driver=virtio-balloon-pci,help
virtio-balloon-pci options:
 free-page-hint=<bool>  - on/off
  disable-legacy=<OnOffAuto> - on/off/auto
  command_serr_enable=<bool> - on/off
  guest-stats=<guest statistics>
  deflate-on-oom=<bool>  - on/off
  free-page-reporting=<bool> - on/off
```